# <p:ajax event="change"> wont work on runtime generated data

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, primefaces

I have this:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="facility" value="#{document.facility}">
     <f:selectItem itemLabel="A" itemValue=""/>
     <f:selectItem itemLabel="B" itemValue=""/>
     <f:selectItems value="#{document.facilities}"/>
     <p:ajax actionListener="#{document.test}" update="project" event="change"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

`document` is the managed bean, that has method `getFacilities()` that return a list of items, let say `C`, `D`, `F`. So the drop down list would be like:

```
A
B
C
D
F
```

If I click on `B`, then the method `test()` would get invoke. I log it. But if I click on the runtime generated data `C`, `D`, `F`, then the method `test()` did not invoke at all. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scope of the Managed Bean has to be at least ViewScoped, if u leave the scope by default, which is RequestScoped, it will not work